# Auditing sql server changes with triggers and different user id from nodejs

Tags: sql-server, node.js, audit, userid

I'm building a 3-tier application with AngularJS, NodeJS+Express and SQL Server. I'm now sending each individual query from the backend to the database to be executed. Thought that's working well, I have now the legal requirement to audit many changes in the database.

For that, I thought about using triggers. However, the problem is that the user identified in the web application is different from the generic user logged into the database, so I don't know how to deal with this.

I thought about converting every query in the backend to a call to a stored procedure, passing each time the user id as a extra field from the frontend to the backend. However, the user id I get here is not the database user. I can't use a temporary table, as I have read in other posts, because this database is about to be accessed at the same time by thousands of users, so it's not secure in my case. I also saw others solutions, but applied to Postre (I need a generic solution, because this application has different versions, working with SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL). Finally, I can't also write code nor configurations in the server for each user, because potential clients will try the trial version without human intervention.

I need a solution that doesn't overload the performance, so it's important for the success of this application.

Thank you very much.